# Postgresql edit gone wrong on Ubuntu. Error every time I use sudo apt-get install

Tags: linux, postgresql, maven, ubuntu

A few months back I edited the PostgreSQL version 8.2.19 source code in Ubuntu OS to change the algorithm of the buffer manager in it. I don't remember what I exactly did but I did something wrong (clearly) so now whenever I try to install a new program, I get the following error (even after it installs successfully)

This was after I used the command `sudo apt-get install maven` to install maven. This happens every time I do a `sudo apt-get install <whatever>`, the program installs but this comes up:

Errors were encountered while processing:

```
postgres-xc  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I messed with some files that affect what happens when a sudo apt-get install is done and I'm trying to get this to go away. I have attached a screenshot as well. Can someone help me?

***I need 10 reputation to post an image so it won't let me post a screenshot so here is the end part of the Maven install*****

```
Setting up testng (6.8.7-2) ...   
Setting up libosgi-compendium-java (4.3.0-1) ...  
Setting up libgeronimo-osgi-support-java (1.0-2) ...  
Setting up libwagon-java (1.0.0-2ubuntu2) ...    
Setting up libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java (1.1-2) ...  
Setting up libmaven2-core-java (2.2.1-14) ...  
Setting up libmaven-scm-java (1.3-5) ...  
Setting up libplexus-containers1.5-java (1.5.5-6) ...  
Setting up libsisu-ioc-java (2.3.0-5) ...  
Setting up libaether-java (1.13.1-2) ...  
Setting up libwagon2-java (2.5-1) ...  
Setting up maven (3.0.5-1) ...  
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn to provide /usr/bin/mvn (mvn) in auto mode  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 postgres-xc  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  
root@r-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/home/r# exit  
exit  
r@r-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You have a done a good job posting the errors.  But you really need to supply more information - such as the portion of the code you changed.

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm sorry as I'm not really sure what files I modified. It was a file for postgres to modify the buffer replacement algorithm. But I think I modified a file that Ubuntu uses and executes when I use the apt get-install command. Any idea which files are used while that command is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late post, I figured this out around a year ago. I used the purge method in Ubuntu to completely unintall postgres. It stopped the error.